# Mac OS: Copying many large (100GB+) files from NAS to local RAID

Tags: macos, copy, rsync, nas, synology

I'm facing the problem of frequently copying multiple hundred huge media files (each way bigger than 100GB) from a Synology NAS to a local Thunderbolt RAID via LAN using a Mac. I've tried many different options ranging from Finder to rsync. None of which seem to work great (or even good).

Surprisingly just copying using Mac OS Finder is the fastest option that I tested so far. It averages at about 100MB/s. But for many reasons (error handling, no checksums, .DS-Store problems, etc) this method is not at all satisfactory.

Although I do not need to sync anything (just copy entire directories from A to B), rsync has exactly what I need in terms of features but it seems to be way too slow for this kind of task. It averages at about 50-70MB/s (-vaEWh --progress).

My question is: Am I holding it wrong or is rsync not the right tool for this? What else could be used to copy many very large files at speeds above 100MB/s with a decent amount of monitoring and logging?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring correctly - 100MB/s seems very unlikely off GBE... what protocol are you using? AFP? NFS? Samba? Have you tried FTP in binary mode? Can you attach a second GBE - with a Thunderbolt-GBE adaptor?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm measuring at 3 different points in the network. Peaks are reaching 114MB/s which is not unusual in this setup. I'm using AFP but tested this with other protocols as well (all worse so far). Second GBE won't help. The connection from Mac to NAS is great (as mentioned above). The performance of the tools seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Can you watch the CPU usage on the Synology (using `top` or similar) while doing the copies? NASes sometimes have weak CPUs.